# WebHookIt development -- Y! Pipes extension and replacement

Tags: javascript, node.js, yahoo-pipes

So Y!Pipes is shutting down, no real alternatives exist, especially none quite similar to Y!Pipes.

[WebHookIt](http://neyric.github.io/webhookit/docs/index.html), [here for the sources](https://github.com/neyric/webhookit), seems like a potentially good alternative, keeping the simplicity of Y!Pipes' interface, and quite a potential to do what Y!Pipes does, and more: open-source, javascript generator (allowing to host "pipes" on google scripts for example).

However, that's a project that was launched a few years ago, and the dev left soon thereafter. There is work to be done on it, and the user documentation is next to non-existent.

I know SX is absolutely not a forum but I'd like to use this very generic question: "anyone to help me update and complete WebHookIt?" to gather all contributions on it. If it takes, we'll move on to a fork on github.
WebHookIt is coded in javascript using node.js. I can code a bit in javascript, but I'm a newbie regarding node.js (though I'll be very invested in the project for the time being, and I'll begin by getting on page with node as soon as tomorrow).

I'll start with the installation, for *buntu systems:
First the dependencies: npm (node.js installer), node.js, and mango-db:

- npm:

  - install: `sudo npm install npm -g`
  - check install with `npm -v`
  - you will probably run into trouble later when trying to install webhookit (or anything I think) over the ownership of npm, as I did, if you don't claim it. Hence that generic enough command: `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $HOME/.npm`
- node.js

  - [taaem](https://github.com/taaem/nodejs-linux-installer/releases) has made a script to download the latest node and satisfy dependencies. Download "node-install.sh".
  - make it executable: `chmod +x node-install.sh`
  - execute it: `./node-install.sh`
  - follow instructions.
- mango-db: follow instruction on their [install page](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#install-mongodb). Herein reproduced:

  - add mango-db repository key: `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10`
  - add repository to the sources: `echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list`
  - update package database: `sudo apt-get update`
  - install mango-db packages: `sudo apt-get install mongodb-org*`
  - start mango-db service (it should already be started): `sudo service mongod start`

WebHookIt is installed by first downloading the repository on github. Now, if you try to install right away you'll run into trouble. This is an old project (latest commit is 3 years old), and the developer didn't provide for improvement to npm. Hence the following steps:

- download the sources. With git installed: git clone git://github.com/neyric/webhookit.git
- go into the webhookit folder, just created, and edit "package.json". Here is the list of the required dependencies, amongst other info about the program.
- find the npm line (should be the 27th), and add ">=" before the version number. End result is: `"dependencies": {  ...  "npm": ">=1.1.0-2",  ...  },`
- install! When into the "webhookit" folder, execute: `npm install .`
- a few warnings will pop up, from node being more recent than required by the dependencies. As node is still in the same major version, it shouldn't be a problem (if well developed, a software shouldn't have compatibility problems within a given major revision (eg the first number)).
- start webhookit server! `node server.js`
- start using it, in your web browser, by default at http://localhost:8124

Next step is to figure out what it means when it says "Open a wiring first."...

Comment: I'm also interested, maybe it could be used as a plugin for visual scripting on VSCode.